# Configuring sysTick timer

Tags: timer, embedded, stm32, interrupt

I am trying to configure the Systick Timer to generate a 1ms interrupt. My MCU is STM32F767 and my clock frequencies are as shown below

```
Oscillator = HSE
No PLL
SYSCLK = 25 MHz
AHB Prescaler = 2
HCLK = 12.5 MHz
APB1 Prescaler  = 2
PCLK1 = 6.25 MHz
APB2 Prescaler  = 2
PCLK2 = 6.25 MHz
```

I have configured the clock properly and have verified the frequencies as being correct.

Now the next part is that I want to configure SysTick timer to generate an interrupt every 1 ms. As I understand the `HAL_Delay()` method requires the systick timer to be set for interrupt of 1 ms.

Now since my HCLK is 12.5 MHz so each cycle lasts 0.08 us. To get an interrupt every 1 ms I have to configure the SysTick reload value to be 12500. I am doing exactly that.

```
    HAL_SYSTICK_Config(12500);
    HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);
```

Hoever Now when i call the following code,

```
    while(1){
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        HAL_Delay(1000);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        HAL_Delay(1000);

        counter++;
    }
```

the pin toggles at rate of around 3 seconds instead of 1. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't think the systick is from hclk but rather sysclk.  Check the clock tree in the reference manual.

Comment: no, SysTick timer is sourced from HCLK. In my case both HCLK and SYSCLK are run at same freq since the AHB1 prescaler is 1.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out the solution, I though my HSE was 25 MHz which was not the case, After reading the data sheet of the MCU(dont rely on CubeMX for this value as the default HSE on CubeMX was displayed as 25 MHz which is not the case in case of nucleo-stm32f767zi board.), I found out that HSE is sourced from ST-Link circuitry and frequency of that signal is 8 Mhz and not 25 MHz as i originally thought. That is why my Led was toggling approximately three times slower.